# Ways to differentiate three respiratory signals

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

I have three 1-min respiratory signals I derived from ECG signals. I am wondering if you guys have any suggestion on differentiating those three? The red line represents the experimental signals and the blue ones are the computational results. Clearly, the second one is more representable than the other ones but I am not sure how I can differentiate it programatically or mathematically. I am not really asking for a specific way to process it. More like specific features that can help differentiate different waves below.

[image]

Any suggestions??

Comment: What does FM and AM mean in this context?

Comment: What are you hoping to extract? Amplitude, frequency ?

Comment: anything, I have tried to use prominence, peak width, peak interval differences. I have not used any frequency processing technique yet cuz I think 60 second data is a bit too short?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about ECG-derived respiratory (EDR) signals, but you didn't detail how you obtained them. Please detail your methods. Maybe then it will be easier to understand what each of your signals mean.

By 'experimental signal', I take it that you mean the reference/gold standard annotation of when respiration occurs, am I correct? But you did not detail if this was the onset or end or peak of the breathing cycle, as well as what kind of measure it was (tidal volume, airflow, other measure?)

Edit #1:
As for features, frequency is a good starting point. EDR signals may not evolve the same way as the reference signals but they should evolve at about the same period. If the breathing is controlled during a significant amount of samples, you can compare the frequency of the whole signals. If not controlled, then take segments of more than 2 seconds. You can apply FFT to get the frequency.

Phase will also be of interest, but it will difficult to comment further without knowing the algorithm for calculation of the EDR as well as the reference signal.

Comment: Hi, I am not really looking for a specific method to extract the respiratory signal. More like looking for specific features of the wave that I can use to differentiate the three signals.

Comment: But it is important to know which method you use! In the AM signal, you are detecting the peaks but in the first two, you are detecting the troughs! What EDR signal you use will condition how well you can represent the actual information.

Comment: Hi, I am not really trying to detect the peak now or extract any information related to respiration. I am just trying to characterize the signal I obtained. Those signals are not processed as well.

Comment: In reply to your comment to @ben, 60 second of data is going to give you around 29-30 breath cycle, assuming a breath rate of 1 cycle per 2 seconds (0.5 Hz). I'd say it is sufficient.